# Several producers, one consumer: Avoid starvation

Tags: multithreading, concurrency, producer-consumer

Given an instance of the producer-consumer problem, where several producers send messages to a single consumer: What techniques do you recommend to avoid starvation of producers, when *some* of the messages arrive "at the same time" to the consumer. Until now I am considering:

1. Choosing "non-deterministically" by sampling some probability distribution (not sure how, considering that a different number of messages are arrived at different time stamps).
2. Using some counters and put a producer to sleep for a while after it has send n messages.

Comment: Hard to imagine you have a mutex implementation that doesn't also provides a minimum fairness guarantee.  If that's a problem with the one you use then just throw it away.

Answer (score 1):

If you can have a priority queue I think each producer can have a message sent counter.  And the queue will order based on the messageSent number and the date, such that a message should be sent before another message if its sent number is less then the other message.

In Java

```
class Message { //or you can implement Comparable<Message>
   final Date created = new Date();
   final int messageNumber; 
   public Message(int m ){this.messageNumber = m;}
}
BlockingQueue<Message> queue = new PriorityBlockingQueue<Message>(new Comparator(){
    public int compare(Message m1, Message m2){
        if(m1.messageNumber < m2.messageNumber) return 1;
        if(m2.messageNumber < m1.messageNumber) return -1;
        if(m1.messageNumber == m2.messageNumber) return m1.created.compareTo(m2.created);
    }
});
class Provider{
   int currentMessage = 0;
   void send(){
       queue.offer(new Message(currentMessage++));
   }
}
```

So if Producer 1 adds 5 elements to the queue (first) and Producer 2 adds 1, the queue will have

```
P1: 5
P1: 4
P1: 3
P1: 2
P2: 1
P1: 1
```

Comment: This might result in starvation. In your example, if producer 1 keeps on adding elements, then producer 2 might go into indefinite starvation. producer 2 will never get processed.

Comment: Not necessarily. What I show at the bottom of my answer indicates that P1: 1 will get processed then P2: 1 if Producer 2 puts another element in the queue it will be placed right after P1: 2

Comment: What happens if the P1 keeps on adding elements before P1: 1. That's when the P2 will never be processed

Comment: In Java at least, the BlockingPriorityQueue will eventually allow P2 to add to the queue.  The moment P2 adds to the queue their message will be inserted ahead of all the P1 messages according to the rules of the comparator.  So even if P1 continues to add, because they are incrementing the sentMessage count P2 will always have a count less then P1 so will get processed next.

Comment: What do you mean by eventually?

Answer (score 0):

One of the simplest and best way is to process the messages on the order of their arrival (a simple FIFO list would do the trick). it doesn't matter even if multiple messages come at the same time. By this way, none of the producers will be starved.

One thing I would make sure is the consumer consumes the messages more rapidly than the producers producing the messages. If not it might end up in producers waiting for the consumer and there won't be any advantage on having multiple producers for a single consumer.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Unfortunately they will. Consider a producer being super fast and another super slow. It _could_ be that the slow never gets the chance to be consumed.

Comment: Also, thinking of your second approach, I guess it will be difficult to find ideal value for "n"